# Why does MS SQL allow you to create an illegal column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I recently saw a tweet stating that you could prevent other developers from reading from a table using the `SELECT * FROM TableName` by building your table in the following way:

```
CREATE TABLE [TableName]
(
   [ID] INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
   [Name] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   [DontUseStar] AS (1 / 0)
);
```

It's easy to see that using the `SELECT *` here would try to read the blank column name as 1 divided by 0 (thus causing a divide by zero error), but without a datatype assigned to the column.

Why does SQL allow you to create a column with no assigned data type, with a name it knows will be illegal?

Comment: This computed column has a data type and it is integer because underlying expression (integer divided by integer) is integer.

Comment: The name isn't illegal; the value is.

Comment: There's nothing "illegal" about the column. As detailed below, it's a perfectly acceptable computed column that will _always_ throw an error at run time, which is when the computation takes place. Fascinating, though.

Comment: RunTime is the key here, as @EricBrandt explained.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It a perfectly valid syntax for a computed column. Computed columns can be used to calculate some value on select without actually storing them, although the value can be persisted.

The reason why 1/0 is allowed, is because the actual computed column value not evaluated until runtime. For example the computed column can be defined as columna/columnb, the same error will occur if any row in columnb has a 0 and is , but only if that row/column was selected.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL
    drop table #t;

CREATE TABLE #t 
(a int
,b int
,div as (a/b)
);

INSERT INTO #t
values 
(1,1)
,(2,0);

SELECT * FROM #t WHERE a = 1;
SELECT a from #t; -- NO ERRORS

SELECT * FROM #t WHERE a=2; --WILL RESULT IN AN ERROR
SELECT * FROM #t; --WILL RESULT IN AN ERROR
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 7):

What you have created is a *computed column* and it is quite powerful and useful!

The expression can be anything.  For instance, you could define:

```
CREATE TABLE [TableName] (
   [ID] INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
   [Name] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   NameLength as (LEN(Name))
);
```

This would create a column called `NameLength` and it would always have the length of `Name` when you refer to it -- no `update`s, no triggers, no views.  It just works.

You don't need a type because SQL Server can figure that out.

The error that you have can even be beneficial -- if you *really* want to enforce that users never use `select *`.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's a greate way to create a table which allows no rows to be selected `select * from` . Why one may need such a table?  Who knows, probably to wire a INSTEAD OF trigger to it or something.  Any programming language will allow the code like `x=1/0`, it's not a compiler business to decide why one needs it.

Comment: [allows no rows](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a07a010643fafcbe301b099620dca9f5)? Can you elaborate

Comment: @scsimon correted , no rows can be selected

Comment: But they can, as long as you list the columns explicitly... excluding the computed columns of course

Comment: I'm not flagging it, but this is really a comment, not an answer.